# Fill DropDownList with LINQ query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I want to view this query in `DropDownList` but the result will appear like this
`{family=jac}`

```
var show = (from u in database.tbl_Customer
            where u.moaref == session
            select new { u.Family }).ToList();

DropDownList1.DataSource = show;
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Project the `Family` and not an anonymous object:

```
var show = (from u in database.tbl_Customer
            where u.moaref == session
            select u.Family).ToList();
```